# Generate image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, rendering

This seems quite a simple question, but I found very little documentation about the topic online:

How do I generate an image with Swift?

More specifically, I have an app that tracks scores of a real life game, and saves those scores. I want my users to be able to generate a score board on demand, and export it as an image, for instance to share on Facebook. Most tutorials on UIImage programming seem to be about altering images (like applying filters etc), but this is another breed of programming.

I think generating a scoreboard using HTML/CSS would be a good idea here, as one can generate tables and overviews with that, and then try to export this as a pdf/bitmap/png, but I'm not sure if that's the right solution.

How can I generate my scoreboard?

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to create an image from the scoreboard is to create scoreboard view (`UIView`) users can interact with and when you need the actual image you take a snapshot of the view and save it in the `UIImage` instance. I created an extension of `UIView` that can do that.

```
extension UIView {
    func getImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
        drawViewHierarchyInRect(bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Then you can just call this method on any `UIView` and in your case on scoreboard view.

```
let scoreImage = scoreBoardView.getImage()
```

You will get `UIImage` instance you can later use as PDF or any other image format.

Comment: so, say I call this method on a UITableView, would it work?